# How to execute REST calls from back end

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the below API that when gets called, will return the Result as Shown:

```
app.get('/getAirData', function (req, res) {
  requestApi('http://www.airnowapi.org/aq/observation/zipCode/current/?format=application/json&zipCode=95131&distance=25&API_KEY=1035C2AC-CDB8-4540-97E4-0E8D82BA335A', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
      res.json(body);
    }
  });
});
```

Result:

```
[{"DateObserved":"2016-05-11 ","HourObserved":0,"LocalTimeZone":"PST","ReportingArea":"San Jose","StateCode":"CA","Latitude":37.33,"Longitude":-121.9,"ParameterName":"O3","AQI":25,"Category":{"Number":1,"Name":"Good"}},{"DateObserved":"2016-05-11 ","HourObserved":0,"LocalTimeZone":"PST","ReportingArea":"San Jose","StateCode":"CA","Latitude":37.33,"Longitude":-121.9,"ParameterName":"PM2.5","AQI":37,"Category":{"Number":1,"Name":"Good"}}]
```

This API is trigged at the frontend..
What I want is for an object to run this code every 30 mins or so and store the result in some variable..

The object that will need to call the function is below.

```
function SenObj (id) {
  this.Template = id;
  this.Type = "AirFlow";
  this.Req_ID = "Jessi";

}
//object
var user1 = new SenObj('id');
```

How can the user1 get the log result from http://www.airnowapi.org/aq/observation/zipCode/current/?format=application/json&zipCode=95131&distance=25&API_KEY=1035C2AC-CDB8-4540-97E4-0E8D82BA335A' at the back end itself..

REST calls works fine but how do user1 get the same output at the backend

Really appreciate some help on this.

Much thanks
Jessi

Comment: What's wrong with just doing this from the frontend? Or making an HTTP request from a separate program?

Comment: My requirement is not to make the call from the front end..It should be executed periodically at the back end and stored somewhere in the DB. when the user wishes to see the collected logs, he makes a query to the DB see the collected logs.

Comment: How can I get this done?

Comment: Well, you don't "execute" REST calls from within your server code. You can just create a separate program and use the [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) module in Node to ping the API, parse the response, and do what you want. That's more than enough to push you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Akshat.So you mean to keep the app.get('/getAirData', function (req, res) {} as it is and be invoked by the HTTP module in the Node? How do we write this program to call the getAirData funtion periodically.